# is it true way always keep only one instance of viewmodel in IOC?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xamarin

We register when the application bootstrap in IOC

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<NewsDetailViewModel>(true);
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CompanyDetailViewModel>(true);
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<NewsViewModel>();
```

And always implement the same in page

```
public NewsViewModel Vm =>((ViewModelLocator)Application.Current.Resources["Locator"]).NewsViewModel;

    public NewsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = Vm;
    }
```

and throughout the entire application we used only

```
Application.Current.Resources["Locator"]
```

inited viewmodels.
It seems to me that I was doing something wrong , correct the right way please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also set the `ViewModel` in the XAML code of the view by using the `DataContext` property.

E.g.

```
<Window x:Class="BuildAssistantUI.BuildAssistantWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:BuildAssistantUI.ViewModels">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <VM:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

When you don't want to do it with XAML I think you should use dependency injection. So you inject the `Services`, `ViewModels` etc. in the constructor and you are not calling the IOC container explicit.

See from [IOC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx):

```
public class ConsumerWithInjection
{
    private IDataService _service;
    public ConsumerWithInjection(IDataService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean is it true way viewmodel to do with one or instance or can better always make new ViewMdoel()?

Comment: If you have a shared context and/or the `ViewModel` should store it's state  and/or the `ViewModel` is called very often than the `ViewModel` should be a singleton. When you have e.g. a `View` with a `ViewModel` only for popping up once and displaying some information than you can create always a new `View` and `ViewModel`. Normally your `View`is created once and the depending `ViewModel` is also created once.

Comment: That is, depending on the case. but most often it is singleton, right?

Comment: Very often. Another reason which I have not mentioned before are references. If you have references on your `ViewModel` e.g. on events and you don't clean them up properly you would have a memory leak.